# Regex in R match strings without including what I don't want to include

Tags: r, regex

I have this list of movie directors for the top 250 user rated movies on imdb obtained like this

```
doc <- GET("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top")

pagetext <- content(doc, as = "text")

directors <- str_extract_all(pagetext, '(?<=")[^"]*(?=\\s\\(dir\\.\\))')

dir_table <- sort(table(directors), decreasing = TRUE)

dir_250 <- data.frame(dir_table)
```

This is a data frame of the directors and how many times they appeared on the list. I added my own fake director with the mononym "Billy" to make sure what I'm doing works for mononyms. I decided to consider mononyms as part of the 1st name.

```
dir_250$directors <- as.character(dir_250$directors)
dir_250 <- rbind(dir_250, c("Billy", 1))
```

Getting the last names worked well. I did it like this

```
regex1 <- 
  "((?<=\\s)(O\\'|[Dd]e(l)?(\\sla)?|[Vv](an|on))?\\s*[[:alpha:]]+\\-?[[:alpha:]]+)$"

str_extract(dir_250$directors, regex1)
```

That worked exactly like I hoped with Billy as NA and all the others with their intended last name. The issue came when I tried getting 1st names. The NA is intended and not an issue.

I tried this approach to it

```
regex2 <- 
".*(?=(\\s(O\\'|[Dd]e(l)?(\\sla)?|[Vv](an|on))?\\s*[[:alpha:]]+\\-?[[:alpha:]]+)$)"
str_extract(dir_250$directors, regex2)
```

To show a smaller example of my problem

```
names <- c("Gus Van Sant", "George Roy Hill", "Paul Thomas")
str_extract(names, regex1)

#[1] "Van Sant" "Hill" "Thomas"
```

Exactly as intended. But

```
names <- c("Gus Van Sant", "George Roy Hill", "Paul Thomas")
str_extract(names, regex2)

#[1] "Gus Van"    "George Roy" "Paul"
```

Not as intended. I want "Gus" "George Roy" "Paul".
My problem was that it included stuff like de, von, and van in the 1st names. I tried many fixes including

```
regex2 <- 
".*(?=(O\\'|[Dd]e(l)?(\\sla)?|[Vv](an|on))?)(?=(\\s(O\\'|[Dd]e(l)?(\\sla)?|[Vv](an|on))?\\s*[[:alpha:]]+\\-?[[:alpha:]]+)$)"
str_extract(dir_250$directors, regex2)
```

But I always got the same issue. How can I get just the 1st names with my previously specified criteria for what counts as a 1st/ last name?

Comment: `rbind(., c("Billy",1))` is corrupting your frame, converting what could be numbers into strings, since `c` is not going to give you a mixed-class vector. While it is easy (in this case) to reverse it, that's a bad habit to get into (and inefficient).

Comment: You should add sample data for the names.

Comment: The NA is a non issue. I have a small sample of names now

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this for regex2

```
regex2 <- ".*(?=\\s(O\\'|[Dd]e(l)?(\\sla)?|[Vv](an|on))\\s)|.*(?=(\\s(O\\'|[Dd]e(l)?(\\sla)?|[Vv](an|on))?\\s*[[:alpha:]]+\\-?[[:alpha:]]+)$)|.*"
```

Using Or got me what I needed